# How to plot BARPLOT in LATEX

Tags: plot

I would like to plot Barplot in latex.

here is my data.....

> name S1 S2
>       john white    912  800
>       alan ket 484 400
>       halen koo 309 250
>       daren kalig 291 280
>       arif butt 192 150
>       james seal 142  120

I want to plot barplot similar to this plot.

[image]

Comment: It'd be great if you could show some kind of starting point, no matter how far away it is from your end goal :) To get started, have a look at the `pgfplots` manual by typing `texdoc pgfplots`, and you might also study these results from [pgfplots bar graph:site tex.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=pgfplots+bar+graph+site%3Atex.stackexchange.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Henry Menke answer with some little adds:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
%\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
name;S1;S2
john white;912;800
alan ket;484;400
halen koo;309;250
daren kalig;291;280
arif butt;192;150
james seal;142;120
}\loadedtable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            xbar,nodes near coords,bar width=16pt,bar shift=0pt,
            symbolic y coords={john white,alan ket,halen koo,daren kalig,arif butt,james seal},
            ytick={john white,alan ket,halen koo,daren kalig,arif butt,james seal},
            %x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{-x}},
            xticklabels={0,1000,500,0,500,1000},
        ]
        \addplot[nodes near coords align={left},
                    draw=blue,fill=blue!25,text=blue]
            table[y=name,x expr={-\thisrow{S1}},point meta={-x}] \loadedtable;

        \addplot table[y=name,x expr={\thisrow{S2}}] \loadedtable;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Its perfect. I have managed to put the labels in italics by adding y tick label style={font=\it}. But somehow when I use \usepackage{helvet} \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} it change only Y axis labels font. The x axis values and the coords stays the same default font. How do i change all fonts to Helvetica?

Answer (score 4):

Another version width `pgfplotstable` and `xbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
name;S1;S2
john white;912;800
alan ket;484;400
halen koo;309;250
daren kalig;291;280
arif butt;192;150
james seal;142;120
}\loadedtable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            xbar,nodes near coords,bar width=16pt,bar shift=0pt,
            symbolic y coords={john white,alan ket,halen koo,daren kalig,arif butt,james seal},
            ytick={john white,alan ket,halen koo,daren kalig,arif butt,james seal},
        ]
        \addplot table[y=name,x expr={-\thisrow{S1}},point meta={x*(-1)}] \loadedtable;

        \addplot table[y=name,x expr={\thisrow{S2}}] \loadedtable;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There is a bug with `point meta`. As soon as I introduce a modifier it gets displaced.

> [image]

Comment: Many thanks. It looks great. But can we remove negative sign ? And the stop values spreading outside plot. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3573959 See updated answer.

Comment: I have been looking at the Manual of pgfplots but couldnt find the solution to place y axis labels in italics.Thanks for the code. Yes it looks like a problem with point meta. Do you suggest any solution? Thanks again.....

Comment: Thanks Henry. There is some edits from Tarass which is our answer to text alignment. Thanks again.